# I have created a apex trigger. What is response code salesforce expecting from my endpoint in case of failure?

Tags: apex, trigger

We are returning 200 for success but what should I return for failure?

Comment: You could return error code, error message and list if errors

Comment: Apex triggers cannot perform or receive callouts. Would you please clarify your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about a callout you can check **[this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/errorcodes.htm)** for more information. Here you will find the **Status Codes and Error Responses**
Things like:

> **200**   *“OK” success code, for GET or HEAD request.*
>
> **201**   *“Created” success code, for POST request.*

If you are talking about errors that can be thrown to you in your code yo ushould check the error class **[here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_error.htm)**

**[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm#i1421192)** there is more error related information.

Exception types are also very important to know, **[here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm)**

Exceptions types are more in the line of the type of operation/execution context. Some are :

> **CalloutException**  Any problem with a Web service operation, such as
> failing to make a callout to an external system.
>
> **DmlException**  Any problem with a DML statement, such as an insert
> statement missing a required field on a record.

If that don't cover your needs you can also **[Create Your Own Exception Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_custom.htm)**

Comment: If I want apex trigger to retry than which code do I need to send back?

Comment: @HimanshuMehta can you please update your question and insert your code? We need a bit of more information on what it is that you want to accomplish here. From your initial question it looks like you are firing a callout from a trigger execution (*I assume that this trigger is instantiating the class that makes the call*) , and you are getting a 200 code response.  Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

These are the return codes for callouts.

**200** “OK” success code, for GET or HEAD request.

**201** “Created” success code, for POST request.

**204** “No Content” success code, for DELETE request.

**300** The value returned when an external ID exists in more than one record. The response body contains the list of matching records.

**304** The request content has not changed since a specified date and time. The date and time is provided in a If-Modified-Since header. See Get Object Metadata Changes for an example.

**400** The request couldn’t be understood, usually because the JSON or XML body contains an error.

**401** The session ID or OAuth token used has expired or is invalid. The response body contains the message and errorCode.

**403** The request has been refused. Verify that the logged-in user has appropriate permissions. If the error code is REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, you’ve exceeded API request limits in your org.

**404** The requested resource couldn’t be found. Check the URI for errors, and verify that there are no sharing issues.

**405** The method specified in the Request-Line isn’t allowed for the resource specified in the URI.

**415** The entity in the request is in a format that’s not supported by the specified method.

**500** An error has occurred within Lightning Platform, so the request couldn’t be completed. Contact Salesforce Customer Support.

Comment: Those are in my answer ... this is not a new answer